# Google Pay Setup 2.3.5 p2

Tags: payment-methods, googlepay

I am wanting to add Google Pay Option to my site. I cannot seem to get the information I need to get this setup and installed. Is there any extensions for this? Also do I need to go to Google to setup the payments?

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know paypal supports Google Pay payment. Try out braintree also